# Issue with renaming PDFs in Python from CSV file

Tags: python, csv, pdf

So I have this script that reads a CSV file (the file is as follows):

```
test0
test1
test2
test3
```

Then the script takes a multipage PDF file (4 pages in this example), and splits it into 4 separate pages, naming them as 'document-pages1', 'document-pages2' etc.

What I'd like to get it to do, is name the split page files to their equivelent location in the CSV file.

So a 4 page PDF would correlate  to the 4 row csv file.  Unfortunately, I'm at a loss for how to implement this part.

My code so far is as follows:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import csv

def readcsv(filename):
    ifile = open(filename, "rU")
    reader = csv.reader(ifile, delimiter=";")

    rownum = 0
    a = []

    for row in reader:
        a.append(row)
        rownum += 1

    ifile.close()
    return a

filepath = input("Filepath: ")
filename = input("File name: ")

csv = readcsv(filepath + filename)

inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open("test.pdf", "rb"))

for i in range(inputpdf.numPages):
    output = PdfFileWriter()
    output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i))
    with open("document-page%s.pdf" % i, "wb") as outputStream:
        output.write(outputStream)
```

Any help at all would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up fixing my own issue as follows:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import csv

def readcsv(filename):
    ifile = open(filename, "rU")
    reader = csv.reader(ifile, delimiter=";")

    rownum = 0
    a = []

    for row in reader:
        a.append(row)
        rownum += 1

    ifile.close()
    return a

filepath = input("Filepath: ")
filename = input("File name: ")

csv = readcsv(filepath + filename)

inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open("test.pdf", "rb"))

for i in range(inputpdf.numPages):
    output = PdfFileWriter()
    output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i))
    with open(str(csv[i]).translate(str.maketrans('','',"[]'")) + ".pdf", "wb") as outputStream:
        output.write(outputStream)
```